# Re-trigger event from event

Tags: events, dojo

Here's a search box module (heavily sanitised to satisfy boss).  It all works, apart from the `more` event.  I get the results, they appear, and the "load more" div appears.

On clicking `more` i would like the `search` event to rerun. In `more`, i do some trivial session calculations which i need to pass to the `search` event, which works.  The `click()` does not.

I've tried moving the `more` event outside of the `search` event, without success.

[This fiddle seems to work, albeit with the node ID instead](http://jsfiddle.net/hEHcf/50/).

```
define([
'dojo/dom',
'dojo/dom-construct',
'dojo/on',
'dojo/query'
'dojo/domReady!'
], function(
dom,
domConstruct,
on,
query
) {

var search = {

    display: function(){

        sb = '<div id="searchWrapper" class="searchWrapper"><h3>Search</h3>
<input id="searchString" type="text" />';

        sb += '<h3>Search</h3><select id="sBy">';
        sb += '<option value="0">Choose...</option>';
        sb += '<option value="f">Foo</option>';
        sb += '<option value="b">Bar</option>';
        sb += '<option value="fb">Foo & Bar</option>';
        sb += '</select>';

        sb += '<div class="searchBtn">
<button type="button" id="search">Search</button></div>';
        sb += '</div>';

        domConstruct.place(sb, dom.byId('body'), 1);

        on(dom.byId('search'), 'click', function(e){

            var r = thisIsWhereDataIsRetrieved(params, whatever);

            // r is the response from the db call
            if(typeof r === 'object'){

                var sr = 'here are the results!';

                for (var result in r) {

                    sr += 'this particular result';

                }

               if(r.length === 50) {
                  sr += '<div id="more" class="more">Load More</div>';
               }
                domConstruct.place(sr, dom.byId('searchWrapper'), 'last');

            }

            on(query('.more'), 'click', function(e){

                // get next results having done stuff
                // to track the state of the search, which works
                dom.byId('search').click(); <<<<< not working

            });


        });

    }

}

return search;
```

});

EDIT: I got around this by re-calling `thisIsWhereDataIsRetrieved` inside the `more` event and appending the next results before the `more` node, but it still seems as though it'd be better to do what i can't!

EDIT2: added `more` node!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use something else than an anonymous function.
For instance, something like this:
(note you may need to have a better construction than the actual method, using query may have side effects if you do not clean properly the dom. I encourage you to write a proper widget and to use attach-points)

```js
define([
  'dojo/dom',
  'dojo/dom-construct',
  'dojo/on',
  'dojo/query'
  'dojo/domReady!'
], function(
  dom,
  domConstruct,
  on,
  query
) {

  var search = {

    display: function() {

      sb = '<div id="searchWrapper" class="searchWrapper"><h3>Search</h3>
<input id="searchString" type="text" />';

      sb += '<h3>Search</h3><select id="sBy">';
      sb += '<option value="0">Choose...</option>';
      sb += '<option value="f">Foo</option>';
      sb += '<option value="b">Bar</option>';
      sb += '<option value="fb">Foo & Bar</option>';
      sb += '</select>';

      sb += '<div class="searchBtn">
<button type="button" id="search">Search</button></div>';
      sb += '</div>';

      domConstruct.place(sb, dom.byId('body'), 1);

      var onSearchClick = function(e) {

        var r = thisIsWhereDataIsRetrieved(params, whatever);

        // r is the response from the db call
        if (typeof r === 'object') {

          var sr = 'here are the results!';

          for (var result in r) {

            sr += 'this particular result';

          }

          if (r.length === 50) {
            sr += '<div id="more" class="more">Load More</div>';
          }
          domConstruct.place(sr, dom.byId('searchWrapper'), 'last');

        }

        on(query('.more'), 'click', function(e) {

          // get next results having done stuff
          // to track the state of the search, which works
          onSearchClick();

        });


      }
      
      on(dom.byId('search'), 'click', function(e) {

          // get next results having done stuff
          // to track the state of the search, which works
          onSearchClick();

        });
    }

  }

  return search;
});
```

Comment: Yes!  Thanks, @ben, that did the trick.  I now hate you a little bit as i have to spread this new knowledge around my code where, umm, some dodginess may have occurred. JK ;)

I've been struggling with Dojo and it's hockey stick learning curve for a while now, but am coming to really appreciate what using it is doing to improve my understanding of code concepts/patterns and javascript in general.  That said, sometimes it feels like stepping into a car without any instruction:  "There's a brake!?"

Comment: I just re-read your reply, and I'm slightly disturbed when you say " I encourage you to write a proper widget and to use attach-points", as that suggests i'm not doing something pretty obvious/important and have little grasp of where to start and how to apply to my code.  I don't want to veer off the original question, but if you've got any handy hints/links that'd be grand!

Comment: @FishBarFood, everyone starts by hating dojo, then the more you use the more you questiuon yourself how you did before... And in the end, after some time, you only want to use Dojo... For the widget, a very good start is this tutorial: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/quickstart/writingWidgets.html